# JBoss CXF policy type config?

Tags: cxf, jboss7.x

I am migrating an application running inside Weblogic 12c to JBoss EAP 4.3.

A piece of the application backend communicates with a secure remote webservice. I imported a trusted peer cert into my cacerts and also provided an identity keystore to identify the app as a trusted client of the remote webservice.

When the webservice is called, the SSL handshake is successful as shown from the SSL debug logs that I have enabled (via -Djavax.net.debug=ssl), so at least a big part of the communication is working

However I am getting an error on the client when trying to process the webservice response:

```
"None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied."
```

I guess part of this is because Weblogic seems to use its own implementation of jax-ws while JBoss uses Apache CXF.

A bigger problem for me though is that the client web service code is encapsulated in a jar file in my application and I cannot really modify it.

So I am looking for some way to make the client policy type(s) match that of the server - at least this is what I think I need to be doing ?

The WSDL of the server says the following:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
    targetNamespace="http://www.bbbbb.net/katws/bbbbbEndPointService"
    name="bbbEndPointService"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wssutil="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.bbb.net/bbbws/bbbEndPointService"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsp:UsingPolicy wssutil:Required="true"/>
  <wsp:Policy wssutil:Id="Wssp1.2-2007-Https-ClientCertReq.xml">
    <ns1:TransportBinding xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <ns1:TransportToken>
```

I am really not sure what i can do.. if theres some way I can provide a cxf.xml file or something?

thanks